# Google Maps V2 - API key not found Error Message

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am currently having trouble adding google maps, direction and places API. I enabled all the API and I have an API browser key which works as I have tested it out.

I was just wondering if anyone is able to help me and resolve the issue I am having. I have checked the manifest file and I have created a string file to hold the API however it brings up an error which I do not understand.

**java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml**

Comment: I have tried all the possible solutions, please anyone help resolve this problem i am currently facing.

Comment: Paste Java code where you inflating layout.

Comment: Remove xmlns namespace from fragment. It is already added.

Comment: @androidnoobdev How your questions and comments are related to the question?

Comment: @Maddie_J Do check with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30877372/1384010

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I am not asking questions. He had already added namespace twice so I thought may be it can be issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

**inside** `<application>`, not outside as you currently have.

Comment: With the same error? Are you using newest Google Play Service?

Comment: I have now fixed this problem by rebuilding and cleaning my project. Thank you all for your suggestions anyway.