# InflateException: Error inflating class fragment, Binary XML Line #1

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following error being raised :

```
com.example.thejdeep.healthpal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.thejdeep.healthpal, PID: 21085
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thejdeep.healthpal/com.example.thejdeep.healthpal.Hospitals}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)   
                                                                                 at    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
                                                                                at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.r.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:115)
                                                                                at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:155)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:6074)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:72)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:62)
                                                                                at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                                                                                at uqw.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:179)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:99)
                                                                                at uqv.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:62)
                                                                                at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzI(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzJy(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1184)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3412)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
                                                                                at com.example.thejdeep.healthpal.Hospitals.onCreate(Hospitals.java:23)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6682)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
02-19 14:27:36.110 21085-21085/com.example.thejdeep.healthpal    E/AndroidRuntime:     
at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

This is my source code :

```
public class Hospitals extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{
private GoogleMap mMap;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState ){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hospitals);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

And this is my XML file (R.layout.activity_hospitals)  :

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.thejdeep.healthpal.Hospitals" />
```

This is my Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.thejdeep.healthpal">
<uses-permission     android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"      />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Home"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Hospitals"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Restaurants"
        android:label="Map">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityTracker"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I have tried to change the android:name to class too, but it isnt working.
I have the API key set-up correctly as a string value.

Can someone point out to what is going wrong in this code ?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace. There should be many more lines after the `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment`, and they will help determine where exactly things are going wrong.

Comment: Added the complete Log. Thanks so much in advance

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml` -- for some reason, it does not like where your API key is.

Comment: where should I be placing it then ?

Comment: The manifest in your question looks fine, so I am not quite certain what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Try use your actual API_KEY string value instead of @string/ reference.

If everything will be OK, you can try move this key to xml and provide reference as it is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30877372/1533933

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped !